# how can I list my own github repos with octokit

Tags: ruby, git, github

I have been using octokit and I can't figure out at all how to list repos from my own personal organization with octokit. I can list repos for other orgs, but I cant for the life of me cant get my own repos. I have the read docs over multiple times.

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => github_access_key)
client.repos
```

That api call keeps listing repos from other orgs I am in, not repos from my personal organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.repos(client.user, affiliation: "owner")
```

Should do it. For a list of options, see https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories.

In case you're wondering here's the [source code](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/51fc9cf0a23fad713c0fdef0a14782f590234780/lib/octokit/client/repositories.rb#L56-L75) for the Octokit method.